# warning C4715: 'bankingMenu' : not all control paths return a value (C++)

Tags: c++

this is my code for bankingMenu, i keep getting that error and I've done what i can to my knowledge to try and fix this but to no avail.. any suggestions?

```
bool bankingMenu(bool menuFlag)  //banking menu 
{

    char choice;
    bool flag = false;
    bool flag2 = menuFlag;
    //print login menu
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<" BANK MENU"<<endl;
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<" A. SHOW ACCOUNT BALANCE"<<endl;
    cout<<" C. MAKE A WITHDRAWAL"<<endl;
    cout<<" D. WRITE A CHECK"<<endl;
    cout<<" E. SHOW ALL TRANSACTIONS"<<endl;
    cout<<" F. LOGOFF ACCOUNT"<<endl;

    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"PLEASE ENTER YOUR SELECTION"<<endl;
    //enter choice of action
    cin>> choice;
    //change input to uppercase
    choice = toupper(choice);
    //input validation for choice
    while( flag == false)
    {
        if(choice != 'A' && choice != 'B' && choice != 'C' && choice!= 'D' && choice!= 'E' && choice!= 'F')
        {
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"\n";
            cout<<"ERROR!! YOU HAVE ENTERED AN INVALID CHOICE. PLEASE ENTER A VALID OPTION."<<endl;
            cin>> choice;
            //change input to uppercase
            choice = toupper(choice);
            continue;
        }
        flag=true;
    }
    //switch for action to be taken with the choice value
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'A' : cout<< "YOU HAVE ENTERED A. \n";
        break;
    case 'B' : cout<< "YOU HAVE ENTERED B. \n";
        break;
    case 'C' : cout<< "YOU HAVE ENTERED C. \n";
        break;
    case 'D' : cout<< "YOU HAVE ENTERED D. \n";
        break;
    case 'E' : cout<< "YOU HAVE ENTERED E. \n";
        break;
    case 'F' : flag2= false;
        //returns to the login menu
        return flag2;
        break;
    default: ;
    }}
```

how can i fix this error?

Comment: What is it supposed to return when `choice` is not `'F'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `return flag2;` (or true or false) at the end of the method to be sure you have a return value even if choice is  something other than 'F'.

Comment: i have return flag2 at the bottom. is it in the wrong place?

Comment: Yep - your return is only in the `case F` branch of the switch, any other value will fall through and not return anything.

Comment: @NiNjAkltTy09 any code in the `case 'F':` section only runs if the user typed 'F'.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a warning, not an error. Your code will compile and run, but the warning is the compiler saying "This might not do what you thought it did! You might want to double-check it!"

And the reason it says "not all control paths return a value" is that your function doesn't always return anything. Specifically, it only returns anything if you enter 'F'. To fix it, make your function always return something.

Comment: i am using visual studio 2012 and i does not let it compile nor run

Comment: Anything that says "warning" does not stop your code compiling or running. Anything that says "error" does.

Comment: A lot of compilers allow you to treat warnings as errors. In my book this one really deserves to be an error!

Comment: They usually display "error" instead of "warning" when treating warnings as errors, AFAIK.

Comment: According to the C++ standard, this code must compile and run. (if we include iostream, main, etc).  The behaviour is only undefined in the case the user doesn't enter `'F'` In other words, the program has to work correctly if the user runs it and only enters `'F'`.